# How do I make a post request with my token coming from local storage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, fetch-api

Having problems getting this to work, although it works when tested with Postman:

```
export const addAdmin = (values) => async (dispatch) => {    

    var add = localStorage.getItem('user');
    
    const res = await fetch('https://capitalluxurydev.xyz/v1/admin/createadmin', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify(values),
        headers: {
            Authorization: add,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        },
        credentials: 'same-origin',
    });
    try {
        const data = await res.json();
        console.log(data);

        return;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);

        return;
    }
};
```

I keep getting a response of invalid JSON construct:

```
{data: null
error: "invalid json construct"
message: ""
statuscode: 422
}
```

But works perfectly on https://hoppscotch.io/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am Brazilian and therefore I speak Portuguese, but I will use the translator to try to help you.

O `postman` coloca automaticamente na `Authorization`  o prefixo `Bearer [your_yoken]`. Tente colocar algo como:

```
    headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${add}`,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    }
```